# fast-csv is throwing exception : column header mismatch expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to validate data using fast-csv.
My code looks like

```
var fileName = req.files.uploadcsv.path;
var fs = require("fs");

var stream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);

var csv = require("fast-csv");

csv
    .fromStream(stream, {
        headers: true
    })
    .validate(function(data) {
            if (data.age > 18)
                return false;
            else
                return true;

        }

    }
```

It works fine for every file I uploaded but if I uploaded file with extra data, it says 
Error: Unexpected Error: column header mismatch expected: 5 columns got: 6
Actually the file has 5 headers but data set it contains have 6 records.
I want to catch this error so that I can point users to error.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED:**
This is because of the fast csv throwing an error as it thought a new column was added. so use **discardUnmappedColumns** option that throws away extra columns

```
 csv.fromStream(stream, {
    headers: true,
    discardUnmappedColumns: true
}).validate(function(data) {
        if (data.age > 18)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it. Solution to the above problem is:

```
.on("error", function(data){
   return false;                         
 })
```

I have implemented this code after .validate() and it worked.

Comment: In my case both, returning `false` on error or [strictColumnHandling](https://c2fo.io/fast-csv/docs/parsing/options#strictcolumnhandling)  didn't help,especially in large files with many types of data since it broke parsing. I found out that [discardunmappedcolumns](https://c2fo.io/fast-csv/docs/parsing/options#discardunmappedcolumns) did the trick though

Answer (score 0):

In case this may help somebody in the future:
I experienced the same error and noticed that one of my rows contained a , -- resulting in fast csv throwing an error as it thought a new column was added. Resolved by escaping the 'cell' in quotation marks.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this too:

```
csv
.fromStream(stream, {
    headers: true,
    strictColumnHandling: true
})
.validate(function(data) {
    if (data.age > 18)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
.on("data-invalid", function(data){
    // do something like log for example
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what `strictColumnHandling: true` is doing in order to solve this? Thanks.